# Time page load and display in layout footer

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Best solution for timing the page load from as early as possible in the app process, and displaying in the layout footer, without modifying Cake source?

Comment: Check out debugkit: https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it gives you render times and controller action processing times, which are more fine grained and let you aim at what you're trying to speed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited solution.** Credit to [Everton Yoshitani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346039/everton-yoshitani).

```
// app/Layouts/default.ctp

echo round(microtime(true) - TIME_START, 3);
```

Comment: There is constant defined for that by cakephp you can use TIME_START you can check in the book http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html
and subtract as everyone pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code, but if you wanted *even* more accurate, use a constant in`APP/webroot/index.php` right at the top:

```
<?php
// set a constant for use in app/view/layout/default.ctp
define('MTIME', microtime(true));
/**
 * PHP 5
 *
```

and layout:

```
// see app/webroot/index.php for constant declaration
echo round(microtime(true) - MTIME, 3);
```

as this file is the very first one accessed (assuming using `.htaccess`). This relies on you using a constant in an unexpected place.

`bootstrap.php` is generally the place to put code like this, but a simple comment in your `webroot/index.php` explaining why the constant is there would clarify any confusion for anyone reading your code.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you are saying in the last couple of sentences. *"This relies on you using a constant in an unexpected place, perhaps (in bootstrap.php it is logical to put code like this. Nothing a comment couldn't fix."* Can you clarify what you mean?